# Angular 10 - how to initialize an Array of class objects?

Tags: angular

so let's say I have this class:

```
export class Card {
    public id: string;
    public title: string;
  
    constructor(title: string = "") {
      this.id = uuid();
      this.title = title;
    }
  }
```

now in my component I can do:

```
myCard: Card = new Card();
```

which will initialize an Object Card, with the default values set in the constructor.

What if I want to create an `array` of `5 Card` `objects`?

I cannot find the right syntax, I tried:

```
cards: Array<Card> = new Array(5)[Card];
```

and similar combinations but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too pretty, but it'll do:

```
cards: Card[] = new Array(5).fill(null).map(() => new Card());
```

Comment: ok I assumed there was a syntax for this, but apparently not, and your solution looks the cleanest one

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
cards: Card[] = [];
```

If you want 5, can do something like this (too ugly!):

```
cards: Card[] = [new Card(), ...];
```